# Cómo eliminar la figura anterior (graph.DrawCircle) sin eliminar la imagen de fondo?

Tags: python, graph

Necesito cargar una imagen que sería el "fondo", y en esta imagen colocaré una serie de círculos cuando se cumpla una condición. (generados mediante graph.DrawCircle )

Y cuando se cumpla otra condición, elimine todos los círculos anteriores(que únicamente será uno)
y el fondo siempre debe permanecer en todo momento y coloque el nuevo círculo.

Mi pregunta, ¿hay alguna manera de actualizar y eliminar estos círculos, es decir, cuando coloco el segundo círculo, se elimina el anterior??

```
from PIL import Image
im1 = Image.open('C:/background.png') # size = 1065x460px
layout = [sg.Graph(canvas_size=(1065, 460), graph_bottom_left=(0, 0), 
graph_top_right=(1065, 460), key="-GRAPH-")]

graph = window.Element("-GRAPH-")
def circle_position(x,y,r):
    graph.DrawCircle((x,y), r, line_color='red')



elif (event =="Display Error Code") or (event == 'Submit'):

    # Borrando circulo anterior antes de colocar el nuevo (Pero me borra el background)
    graph.Erase()
    circle_position(324,257,16)

if (values[0] == "1002") :  # 2nd circle

     # Borrando circulo anterior antes de colocar el nuevo(Pero me borra el background)
    graph.Erase()
    circle_position(342,303,16)
```

Gracias de ante mano

Answer (score 0):

Al final trasteando (conste que soy un aficionado malo a la programación) lo mas fácil para mí fue eliminar el circulo anterior y el background(es decir limpiar todo)  y después volver a colocar el background y el nuevo circulo con:

```
graph.Erase()
```